# Dockerized Vue SPA with different API urls depending on where it is running

Tags: docker, vue.js, devops

I got this docker image of my Vue.js app that fetches data from an api running in a java backend. In production the api is running under `app.example.com/api`, in staging it will run under `staging.example.com/api` and when running it on my local computer the api will be running at `localhost:8081`. When running the frontend on my computer I might be using `vue cli serve` in the project folder, or it might be started as a docker image using docker-compose. The backend is always running as a docker image.

I would like to be able to use the same docker image for local docker-compose, deploy to staging and deploy to production, but using a different url to the backend api. As a bonus it would be nice to be able to use vue-cli serve.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Assuming you can avoid using CORS, your front end router should just use the <HOST>/api every time. It shouldn't matter where it's hosted, it'll always use its current host name. `vue serve` won't give you any production benefits such as bundling or minification.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but was having problems with how to make that approach work locally using different services. Lets say there are one fronend running on port 80, and a backend api running on port 8080. How would I map this service to localhost:80/api/? Would I have to setup a nginx/apache proxy?

Comment: setting up a nginx proxy as part of the docker-compose file would solve this problem locally. No need for CORS setup..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an environment variable containing the API url and then use the environment variable in your Vue app.

The Vue cli supports environment variables and allows you to use environment variables that start with `VUE_APP_` in your [client-side code](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code). So if you create an environment variable called `VUE_APP_API_URL` in the environment you're running the Vue CLI in (whether it is Docker or on your host machine) you should be able to use `process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL` in your Vue code.

If you're running Vue CLI locally, you can just run `export VUE_APP_API_URL="localhost:8081"` before running `vue cli serve`.

Docker also supports [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables). For example, if your SPA Docker service is called "frontend", you can add an environment variable to your Docker Compose file like this:

```
frontend:
  environment:
    - VUE_APP_API_URL
```

If you have the `VUE_APP_API_URL` environment variable set in the host you're running Docker from it will be passed on to your "frontend" Docker container. So, for example, if you're running it locally your can run `export VUE_APP_API_URL="localhost:8081"` before running Docker Compose.

You can also pass through environment variables using an [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file). You can read more about environment variables in Docker Compose files [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

you can create .env files
env file for development, production ...
check this out for better details:
https://dev.to/ratracegrad/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-vue-js-4ko7